# Make TypeScript see global types bundled by dependency

Tags: typescript

I have a package which exposes a couple of web components. It also exposes JSX types for them so that they can be used in React without TypeScript complaining. After installing my dependency, the folder structure looks like this:

```
./node_modules/
  my-pacakge/
    src/...
    index.d.ts
    package.json

// package.json
{
    ...
    "types": "./index.d.ts",
    ...
}

// index.d.ts
declare namespace JSX {
    export interface IntrinsicElements { 
        'my-component': any,
        'my-other-component': any,
        'my-third-component': any
    }
}
```

When I try to use `<my-component></my-component>` from within JSX, I get the error `Property 'my-component' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.`

If I manually copy the `index.d.ts` file into `./node_modules/@types/my-package/index.d.ts` then the error goes away.

If I place an `import 'my-package';` anywhere in my code then the error goes away too.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get TypeScript to see my types without either publishing the module separately in the `@types` repo or adding the import somewhere in my code. The web components provided by this package are commonly pulled in through a script tag, so having an explicit import of the package just so TypeScript picks up the types feels weird.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a better solution than just putting the import in your code.  Somehow TypeScript has to be told to load the file containing the declarations.

Comment: Is it by design that TypeScript only auto loads the files under @types?

Comment: Yes.  AIUI, this is because there are several DefinitelyTyped packages (e.g., `@types/node`) that provide global declarations for particular target environments, and it would be a pain to make all users of these packages import them explicitly, but automatic loading of non-`@types` packages was judged to do more harm than good.  You can configure this behavior a bit (see the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)), but I would recommend just using the import.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen If you want to summarize your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a better solution than just putting the import in your code.

Note that by default, TypeScript's [`types` mechanism](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) automatically loads the main type declaration files of packages in the `@types` scope (which on the main npm registry corresponds to DefinitelyTyped), but this feature does not apply to other packages.  I believe this is because there are several DefinitelyTyped packages (e.g., `@types/node`) that provide global declarations for particular target environments, and the convenience of loading these declarations without the user having to write `/// <reference types="node"/>` was judged to outweigh the risk of accidents, but the same was not considered to hold for arbitrary non-`@types` packages.  You could try to get this mechanism to load all your packages by adding your main `node_modules` directory to `typeRoots`, but it's probably more sensible to just use the import.